# How can I link a select with my tablehead?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I want to know how can I link my tableheads with a select ?

Here is a screen of how it looks

[image]

I just want to add a town in a column I've chosen before.

Here is my code :

```js
function addRow() {
    var table = document.getElementById("table");

    var row= table.insertRow(-1);

    var column1 = row.insertCell(0);
    column1.innerHTML += document.getElementById("ville").value;
}
```

```html
<h2>Test</h2>
<form method="post" action="">

    <select id="select">
        <option selected disabled>Choose one</option> 
        <option>Option A</option>
        <option>Option B</option>
        <option>Option C</option>
        <option>Option D</option>
        <option>Option E</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" name="ville" id="ville" />
    <input type="button" onclick="addRow();" value="Save"/>
  
</form>


<table id="table" style="margin: 30px; border-spacing: 20px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Option A</th> 
            <th>Option B</th>
            <th>Option C</th>
            <th>Option D</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>TEST</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the select list provide you with the column number the new text needs to go in.  Something like:

```js
function addRow() {
    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var columnpicked = document.getElementById("select").value;
    for (let i = 0; i <= columnpicked; i++) {
      row.insertCell(0);
    }
    row.cells[columnpicked].innerHTML += document.getElementById("ville").value;
}
```

```html
<h2>Test</h2>


    <select id="select">
        <option selected disabled>Choose one</option> 
        <option value=0>Option A</option>
        <option value=1>Option B</option>
        <option value=2>Option C</option>
        <option value=3>Option D</option>
        <option value=4>Option E</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" name="ville" id="ville" />

    <input type="button" onclick="addRow();" value="Save"/>


<table id="table" style="margin: 30px; border-spacing: 20px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Option A</th> 
            <th>Option B</th>
            <th>Option C</th>
            <th>Option D</th>
            <th>Option E</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>TEST</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Note that you only had four columns in your example - so, I've added an Option E column to match the select list items.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I want except it add a row everytime I add something, I think I need to check if the cell is empty and if not, I can add a row, right ?

Comment: I was actually wondering that. I did think that it would make more sense to populate just one row with up to five input texts. The issue would be the `addRow()` function itself as this does the insert of a new row and creates enough `td` items as needed to output the text in the right column. If a row already exists, the select list value will tell you what`td` the text should go in - it would go in `row[0].cells[select.value].innerHTML`. So, update the code to point to `table.rows[0]` and then just update the right `td`.  If the row doesn't exist, you can add it first.

Answer (score 0):

I will leave the other answer there in case we need to go back to it.  From your comments, I think you need to do something like:

```js
function addRow() {
  // Get the tbody element - NOTE: an id has been added to that to make it easier to find
  var table = document.getElementById("tablerows");
  // Get the rows in the tbody element
  var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  // If there are no rows, create one
  if (rows.length == 0) {
    tbody.insertRow();
  }
  // Get the first row
  var row = rows[0];
  // Get the column selected by the user
  var selected = document.getElementById("select").value;
  // Check if the row has enough td items to put the text into the selected column
  if (row.cells.length - 1 < selected) {
    // If it hasn't, create them
    for (let i = 0; i < selected; i++) {
      let td = document.createElement("td");
      row.appendChild(td);
    }
  }
  // Get the text to be inserted
  var ville = document.getElementById("ville");
  // Insert the text in the selected column
  row.cells[selected].innerHTML = ville.value;
}
```

```html
<h2>Test</h2>


    <select id="select">
        <option selected disabled>Choose one</option> 
        <option value=0>Option A</option>
        <option value=1>Option B</option>
        <option value=2>Option C</option>
        <option value=3>Option D</option>
        <option value=4>Option E</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" name="ville" id="ville" />

    <input type="button" onclick="addRow();" value="Save"/>


<table id="table" style="margin: 30px; border-spacing: 20px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Option A</th> 
            <th>Option B</th>
            <th>Option C</th>
            <th>Option D</th>
            <th>Option E</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tablerows">
        <tr>
            <td>TEST</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have added an id to the tbody tag as the header row is seen as part of the table's rows collection.  Doing this means that we can target only the rows on the tbody.

---

OK - assuming we are ok for the users to enter text directly in a cell, try:

```js
function addRow() {
  var t = document.getElementById("datarows");
  var rtemplate = document.getElementById("newrow");
  var r = rtemplate.content.cloneNode(true);
  t.appendChild(r);
}
```

```css
table {border-collapse:collapse;}
td {height:23px; background-color:white; border:1px solid black; padding:5px; width:100px; vertical-align:top;}
th {border:1px solid black; padding:5px; width:100px;}
td:focus {background-color:lightgreen;}
```

```html
<b>Click on a table cell to add/edit text</b><br>or click to add a new row <button id="newrowbutton" onclick="addRow();">Add new row</button>
<hr>
<table>
  <thead id="headerrow">
    <tr>
      <th>Option A</th>
      <th>Option B</th>
      <th>Option C</th>
      <th>Option D</th>
      <th>Option E</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="datarows">
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable></td>
      <td contenteditable></td>
      <td contenteditable></td>
      <td contenteditable></td>
      <td contenteditable></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<template id="newrow">
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable></td>
      <td contenteditable></td>
      <td contenteditable></td>
      <td contenteditable></td>
      <td contenteditable></td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it's so kind of you ! I've got jsut one question. How can I add a new row when the 1st one is full ?

Comment: **full** as in ALL cells have text in them, or **full** because the cell the user wants to insert text into already contains text?

Comment: I'd say both but I don't know if in the second case, when the user wants to insert text into an empty cell in the 1st row, it will go in the 1st one or in the last row created ?

Comment: I have no idea either - they are your users!!  You could give them the option of inserting a new row if there is text already in the column.  You could overwrite the text.  Or, you could give them a button to insert a new row whenever they wanted.  Each can be done, but it does depend on their requirements.

Comment: Yes I think I'd do that. I'd let it like that and add an option to insert a new row whenever they want because all the column will not be equally filled.

Comment: OK - but there is a problem with that approach.  If they have, say, three rows, and all of those rows have nothing in, say, Option E, and they select Option E from the drop-down, enter some text and click the Save button, where's there text going to go?

Comment: There is actually a different approach you could take.  Let the user click on a cell and prompt them for some text to enter into that cell directly.  Then, they can add as many rows as they like, but it's the clicking on a cell that determines where the text goes.  That also gives them the ability to edit their text if needed.

Comment: Yes that's totally a better approach because I was thinking about how I can edit easily these data but yeah, it will be easier like that.

Comment: OK - I've added a new snippet to this Answer showing you one way you can do that.